# Check if users are logged on your workstation using VBScript

Tags: authentication, vbscript

I need a solution to execute a `script` to check if users are logged on your workstation.

I have stored the list of worstation to question on the file `serverlist_login.txt`

If the user are logged, we write the username in the file `results_login.txt`.

I have tried without success this script, but for all workstation my `username` always appears as a user logged into the workstation. This is not possible

The file `results_login.txt` output:

```
Login Results
 Date And Time : 24/08/2021 11:59:39

 User is connected  : worstation_01
MyDomain\MyUserName
 User is connected  : worstation_02
MyDomain\MyUserName
 User is connected  : worstation_03
MyDomain\MyUserName
```

Any suggestion?

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWrite = 2, ForAppend = 8

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set systems = wmi.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

If Fso.FileExists(Fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\serverlist_login.txt") Then

Set Ts = Fso.OpenTextFile("serverlist_login.txt", ForReading)
strText = Ts.ReadAll
Ts.Close

For Each i In Split(strText, vbCrLf)
   For Each system In systems
      If system.UserName <> "" Then
         Results1 = Results1 & " User is connected  : " & i & vbCrLf & system.username & vbCrLf 
      Else
         Results2 = Results2 & " No user is connected : " & i & vbCrLf
      End If 
   Next
Next

Set Ts = Fso.CreateTextFile("results_login.txt")
Ts.WriteLine "Login Results" & vbCrLf & " Date And Time : " & Now & Vbcrlf
Ts.WriteLine Results1
Ts.WriteLine Results2
Ts.Close()  

Else
   MsgBox vbTab &_
      "Error" & vbcrlf &_
      "Missing, the server.txt to process. You" & vbCrLf & _
      "must create a servers.txt with an IP or" & vbCrLf & _
      "Computer Name, with one per line",4128,"Error"   
End If
```

**Update #01**

```
For Each i In Split(strText, vbCrLf)
   For Each system In Wmi.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_ComputerSystem where Name = '" & i & "'")
      If system.UserName <> "" Then
         Results1 = Results1 & " User is connected  : " & i & vbCrLf & system.username & vbCrLf 
      Else
         Results2 = Results2 & " No user is connected : " & i & vbCrLf
      End If 
   Next
Next
```

Comment: Currently, you are not making any remote WMI calls.  The clue is the period `.` in line 4 `Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")`.  The period `.` should be changed to a variable of the remote system found in your `serverlist_login.txt` file, and moved inside your `For Each i In Split(strText, vbCrLf)` loop.

Comment: @leeharvey1 thanks for reply. Please see **Update #01** in my first question. The file `results_login.txt` output is empty...

Comment: winmgmts: is the WMI call, but if its not in that loop, and not referencing a remote system `i`, then you're still only querying the local `.` system.  Sorry.

Comment: @leeharvey1 I'm sorry. I don't understand your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the loop in question, since comments prevent proper formatting:

```
For Each i In Split(strText, vbCrLf)
   Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & i & "\root\cimv2")
   Set colItems = wmi.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
   For Each Item In colItems
      If Item.UserName <> "" Then
         Results1 = Results1 & " User is connected  : " & i & vbCrLf & Item.username & vbCrLf 
      Else
         Results2 = Results2 & " No user is connected : " & i & vbCrLf
      End If 
   Next
Next
```

Do you see where variable `i` replaces the period `.` above?

Also, your variable `systems` is misleading you.  This is actually just a collection of items returned by WMI for the current system.

So essentially, the main loop above enumerates all systems `i` in your text file; then connects to those systems via `wmi` (impersonating your user account context); then pulls a collection of Win32_ComputerSystem items `colItems` from that system; and finally, enumerates each `item` in the collection to see which usernames are found.